# Yii Custom column in TbGridView with FontAwsome icon by condition

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, font-awesome

I've been trying to render an icon in a column using fontAwesome. I can get it done with an image but I can't get the fontAwesome icon to display based on True/False condition. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code, column 1 is the column I'm trying to display with Fontawesome and doesn't work, column 2 is using image and works fine.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'           => 'vpolicy-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->searchForPolicyIndex(),
'filter'       => $model,
'type'         => 'striped condensed',
'selectableRows'   => 1, // you can select only 1 row!!
'selectionChanged' => 'function(id){ var objectId = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);
if (isNaN(objectId) || objectId == ""){return;} location.href = "'.$this->createUrl('policy/view').
'&id="+$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);}',

'columns'=>array(
  array('name'              => 'has_open_issue',
        'header'            => 'Issues',
        'type'              => 'raw',
        'value'             => '($data->has_open_issue == "N") ? "<i class="icon- fa-check icon-2x"></i>" : "<i class="icon-fa-warning-sign icon-2x"></i>"',
        'filter'            => VFFormUtil::getFilter_YesNo(),
        'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'text-align: center; width: 80px'),
        'htmlOptions'       => array('style'=>'text-align: center; width: 80px'),),
  array('name'              => 'compliance',
        'type'              => 'raw',
        'value'             => 'CHtml::image($data->compliance == "INSUFFICIENT" ? "images/policy_insufficient.png" : "images/policy_sufficient.png", "", array("width"=>25, "height"=>25))',
        'filter'            => VFFormUtil::getFilter_Compliance(),
        'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'text-align: center; width: 80px'),
        'htmlOptions'       => array('style'=>'text-align: center; width: 80px'),),
```

I also tried:

```
'value'=> 'CHtml::tag($data->has_open_issue == "N" ? "<i class="icon-fa-check icon-2x" style="color:green"></i>" : "<i class="icon-fa-warning-sign icon-2x" style="color:red"></i>", "", array("width"=>25, "height"=>25))',
```

and it didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes for the tag attributes i.e

```
'value'=> '($data->has_open_issue == "N") ? "<i class=\"icon- fa-check icon-2x\"></i>" : "<i class=\"icon-fa-warning-sign icon-2x\"></i>"',
```

instead of

```
'value'=> '($data->has_open_issue == "N") ? "<i class="icon- fa-check icon-2x"></i>" : "<i class="icon-fa-warning-sign icon-2x"></i>"',
```